# Why is this method of insertion sort not working?

Tags: c++

In this insertion sort technique, in the while loop condition when I compare `current` and `arr[j]`, the program works but if I compare `arr[i]` with `arr[j]` the program doesn't give the correct output.

Do you have any idea there's a difference although `current` and `i` are same?

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int s){
    for(int i=1;i<s;i++){
        int current = arr[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while(arr[j]>current && j>=0){// if I use arr[i] instead of current the program gives wrong output.
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1] = current;
        printArray(s, arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look carefully, you can notice that if the `while` loop does more than one iteration, it will not compare the same value on second iteration as `arr[i]`is modified by the line `arr[j + 1]`. You set `j` to `i - 1` the then modify `arr[j + 1]` which is the location of `arr[i]`since `j == i - 1` implies that `j + 1 == i`. **You can also use a debugger to follow the program step by step**.

Comment: Review the  _order_ of the two tests in `arr[j]>current && j>=0`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same because you are making operations on the array `arr` in your while loop, through index i, and potentially writing a new value into array[i] when `j+1 == i`, that is why you need to save the current value of arr at index i before the while loop.